# How to Remove an Asset with No Issuer?

Tags: assets, token, trustline

I have an asset in my Stellar wallet, LTZ, which has had the issuing account deleted. I cannot send this asset out of my account, nor can I trade it, and likewise I cannot remove the trustline until the account balance is zero.

Any ideas on how to delete a trustline for an asset with no issuer?

Answer (score 1):

To destroy those tokens permanently, you need to send them to the issuing account address. Tokens will be burned automatically even if the issuer account does not exist on the ledger anymore. After that the trustline can be removed without any problems.

Comment: Usually, that is the case. However, I cannot send the tokens to an address that does not exist. At least using the wallet where the tokens are stored. Maybe Stellar Laboratory? IDK.

Comment: @user2871 Yeah, I checked this using StellarLaboratory before writing a reply. Everything works. Check operations history her for example: https://stellar.expert/explorer/testnet/account/GB4IM7DZZPIAVGITIDW2F2TB6C3NY5SZNCB44XFINFWETPBJEN7OUVQK

Comment: Thanks Orbit Lens. Was able to do it using Stellar Laboratory. Apparently it was an issue with the Lobstr wallet.