# How to remove a trustline of a locked account?

Tags: assets, token, trustline

I have a trustline* which I can't remove because it has assets with non zero balance. The assets are "frozen" so I can't move them to apply the trick mentioned in "https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/4080/how-to-remove-an-asset-with-no-issuer" to remove related trustline.

*The trustline's issuer account is https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBSTRH4QOTWNSVA6E4HFERETX4ZLSR3CIUBLK7AXYII277PFJC4BBYOG
Account lock status:locked

What can I do to remove it?

( tried 'change trust' operation in stellar laboratory without success, error: {"transaction":"tx_failed","operations":["op_invalid_limit"]} )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're in a deadlock. You remove a trustline by setting the limit of the trustline to 0, and you can't set the trustline limit lower than your balance. If the issuer froze you're asset by revoking your authorization, and then locked itself. I don't think there's a way to fix this.

I'm sure this is surprising to many, and it's probably something which should be addressed on the protocol level, maybe by requiring that someone is sponsoring the trustline before it can be revoked.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the assets.

When you have remnants of an asset and they're not worth enough to trade them for another pair, that's the only way to zero that asset, to then be able to remove its trustline.

Stellar network will find the best route for that, even through assets you don't have trustlines to.

Answer (score 0):

I sent mine back to the issuer then removed the asset.